# Transfer data with the least transfer time with dijkstra algorithm

Tags: algorithm, networking, network-programming, dijkstra

Suppose that we have a large network and want to reduce the data transfer time among nodes(source of data and destination node). Can the use of dijkstra algorithm(selecting the shortest path between two nodes) reduce the total data transfer time?

The goal is to transfer the data in a network with the least transfer time.

Comment: Today routers have smart routing algorithms burned into their hardware. I suspect that you can't do better than that. BTW how will you decide what's the shortest path? BTW2 who says that the shortest path is also the fastest?

Comment: If congestion problems, you might be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem